# Upgraded to php 5.4 on my wordpress server and now getting strict standards errors

Tags: php, wordpress

The plugin that is getting errors is WP Download Manager

**Error:**

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/otbm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download-manager/functions.php on line 1879
```

**Line 1879:**

```
if(count($vars['files'])==1) $vars['file_ext'] = end($tmpdata = explode(".", $vars['files'][0]));
```

**also getting this error in admin:**

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/otbm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download-manager/wpdm.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1034
```

I can't find that line as it is all one single line of code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because [in 5.4, the `E_STRICT` error level became part of `E_ALL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). You can still disable it as documented, if you are not in a position to correct the strict standards violations in WP plugins.

Comment: Line 1879 is in error because it passes the result of `explode()` into `end()`.  Instead, since it is stored to `$tmpdata`, you should do `end($tmpdata)` in _another statement_ rather than packing it all into one line.

Comment: Really though, you should petition the maintainer of that WP plugin to correct it upstream.  WP is notoriously bad for coding standards & suppressed or ignored warnings, unfortunately.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Thanks for your help. I am a front end developer and don't know my php real well. :) How would I separate it into another statement?

Comment: Something like `$tmpdata = explode(".", $vars['files'][0]); if(count($vars['files'])==1) $vars['file_ext'] = end($tmpdata);` Should do it. The `explode()` first, followed by the `if()`.